# Will installing Tor on my VPS allow me to hide its IP address?

Tags: security, ip, privacy, tor, vps

I want to hide my VPS's IP from hosts it interacts with across the Internet.

It is my understanding that using Tor on a home computer would work to some extent, will it work as well on a VPS?

Comment: Hide the VPN ip address from whom?

Comment: This question is extremely vague. What do you wanna do with your VPS? WHat do you mean by "hide its IP"? If you want to completely remove your VPS's public IP, the **only** solution is to disconnect it from the Internet.

Comment: I want to hide the IP from the hosts I interact with via VPS.

Comment: For what purpose?  A good VPN already protects your identity far better then TOR does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but from your comments I understand what you intend.

You want to hide your IP when you are working on the VPS and need to download stuff from the internet to the VPS.
The VPS is just a regular computer just like your computer at home (at least in this sense).

So yes: If you install a TOR client on the VPS you can use that just like you do on the computer at home.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you fully understand what 'hiding your IP address' means? You would not be able to receive any website or other data, as your IP address is the place where this gets delivered to.

Imagine you want to order something from Amazon, but you want to completely hide your mailing address. How can that work?

Comment: I would still have access to the VPS via KVM. If I were to run "wget www.exmple.com/index.html"  from the VPS, its IP address would show up on that website's logs. I can't prevent that?

Comment: you can, but the website then would not know where to send the result or your wget. You need to tell the website where to send the answer, and it will log it.

Comment: I see. But why does this work on a home computer? If I install Tor or use whonix, my IP address is hidden from the hosts. How is that different from using a VPS?

Comment: TOR acts like a friend that accepts your Amazon shipments for you and then gives them to you, to stay in the example. Amazon would not know your address, but your friend's address. If you trust your friend (TOR in this case), it will work.

Comment: That is precisely what I wanted to know. So Just to be clear, I _can_ use Tor to anonymise my VPS'?

Comment: Using TOR does not make you anonymize when you connect to a service connected to your actually identity.  There is no way to connect to TOR and not have a party involved that doesn't know WHO you are, and they can tell your using TOR, which means you can be identified.  Connecting to a VPN then TOR just connect you to TOR and increases the latency by ten fold, this answer, while correct fails to mention ANY these short comings